# how to make an item flip direction depending on it's rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a gun that circles my player, but it is upside down when it is facing left, so I wrote a script so that it flips the gun whenever it is rotated when it is greater than 100 degrees and less than -100 degrees, but it doesn't flip at all

```
        if( transform.rotation.z >= 100 && transform.rotation.z <= -100)
    {
        Debug.Log("flip");

        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, -1f, 1f);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("flop");

        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add exactly how it doesn't work instead of just saying it does not work? What currently happens? Also where are you flipping the object? I only see the local scale changing. Are the print outs just not occurring when you expect? Is the game 2D? What perspective?

Comment: it doesn't flip

Comment: That is rather vague. Judging that you are testing the Z axis, it is a 2D game. Is the game top down, side scrolling, 2.5D? What have you tried to get it to work though? None of the current code you posted would flip anything.

Comment: it is 2d top-down game and it flips it by inverting the scale of the object

Comment: I would avoid changing scale to rotate an object. It most likely is going to mess with all other rotation you are trying to do. Is your object a sprite renderer? In that case there is a built in flip field on the component that flips the sprite over a specified axis. Use that instead.

Comment: I did not know that there was a specified flip part on the sprite renderer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all a [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) has **four** components x, y, z **and w!**

They all move in the range `-1` to `1`!

=> If you don't know exactly what you are doing **never** directly use/assign the components of a `Quaternion`!

What you want are probably the [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html).

**BUT** careful here:

> When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.

So instead I would rather compare two directions like your local `transform.right` to the global `Vector3.right` for example (assuming it is **only** rotated on Z of course).

---

Secondly **how can any value be `>= 100` and at the same time `<= -100`?!**

That's impossible to achieve ^^

I guess you would either rather want something between `-100` and `100` using

```
if(something >= -100 && something <= 100)
```

or the other way round and use

```
if(something >= 100 || something <= -100)
```

to get the values between `-180` and `-100` and the values between `100` and `180`.

---

So you would probably use [`Vector3.SignedAngle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SignedAngle.html) like e.g.

```
var zAngle = Vector3.SignedAngle(transform.right, Vector3.right, Vector3.forward);
if(zAngle >= 100 || zAngle <= -100)
```

or directly [`Vector3.Angle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html)

```
var zAngle = Vector3.Angle(transform.right, Vector3.right);
if(zAngle >= 100)
```

Comment: so... I am not super fluent in more advanced coding, so what is SignedAngle? and also, to sound even dumber, I copy-pasted it to replace the if statement, but the SignedAngle is underlined in red.

Comment: @SyntaxError I fixed the missing parameter and would recommend to look into the Unity API in general ;)

Answer (score 0):

because the condition you have written
if( transform.rotation.z >= 100 && transform.rotation.z <= -100)
it is contradicting with itself it can only be true as per this when the value of z rotation is 100

```
   if( transform.rotation.z >= 100 && transform.rotation.z <= -100)
    {
        Debug.Log("flip");

        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, -1f, 1f);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("flop");

        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
    }
```

Comment: okay, that makes sense. how would I though flip it when it is between those two numbers?

Comment: Haven't I said the same? ^^ and note that this is not all of the Issue

Comment: yes, but I want it to flip when it is between -100 and 100, but not 100, 99, 98 etc... instead like 100, 101, 102 etc... to -100